# Calling webservice in Android similar to iOS with httpheaders and parameters

Tags: android, web-services

This is how i call a webservice in iOS.

```
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "reqesturl")!)
    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

    let params = ["key1": value1,  "key2": value2, "key3": value3, "key4": value4] as Dictionary<String, AnyObject>

    request.HTTPBody = try! NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(params, options: .PrettyPrinted)

    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

    request.addValue(SESSION_ID!, forHTTPHeaderField: "sSessionId")

    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) {(data, response, error) in
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            if response != nil {
                let httpResponse = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse
                let status = httpResponse!.allHeaderFields["internalErrors"] as? String
                self.statusCode = Int(status!)

                if self.statusCode != nil {
                    if self.statusCode > 0 && self.statusCode < ERRORCODE.count {
                        if self.statusCode == 8 {
                            APPDELEGATE?.showErrorCode(self.statusCode)
                        }
                        postCompleted(Succeeded: false , CheckinDetails: "Failed")

                    }
                }else {
                    APPDELEGATE?.showErrorCode(78)
                }

            }else {
                postCompleted(Succeeded: false , CheckinDetails: "Failed")
            }
        })
    }
    task.resume()
```

How can I achieve this in Android? I am trying to add Http header fields to web request. Then I am adding parameters to this request. I am new to android development.

Comment: You should take a look at HttpUrlConnection class. Here a small explanation from the android developer training https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html#download. To add request headers use the method setRequestProperty

Answer (score 0):

This could be a complete solution for your use case. Obviously you need a proper way to get the JSON. I suggest you using Jackson or GSON libraries to manage JSON objects and strings.

```
public String httpPOSTrequest(String url, String json) {

    //if request will success, the server response will be saved here
    String response = "";

    try {

        URL urll = new URL(url);
        HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) urll.openConnection();
        conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
        conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setDoOutput(true);


        OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
        writer.write(json);
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
        os.close();

        conn.connect(); //real call starts here

        int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode()

        if (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
             String line;
             BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
             while ((line=br.readLine()) != null) {
                  response+=line;
             }
        }
    } catch (Exception e {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return response;
}
```

Moreover this code need a better error handling but i think could be a good start point.